# Form inputs inside jQuery draggable objects are uneditable

Tags: jquery, forms, input, jquery-ui-sortable, edit

I'm trying to put a form inside an element, on which jQuery sortable is active. There's a DIV element, which is movable (with jQuery sortable), an IMG element, which is used as a handler for moving the DIV and FORM element with inputs inside. Both FORM and IMG els are inside the DIV. Problem is, that **inputs inside the form can't be edited**. When I turn sortable off, it works fine.

Am I doing something wrong or is it a bug? Is there a way to fix it?

Thank you kindly

Comment: I think posting some code will help this question a lot. Even better, a link to a jsfiddle.

Comment: I can tell you why it happens, but i don't know of a way around it. Basically, jQuery is catching the mouse events inside of the draggable div (sortable uses draggable) which prevents you from clicking on the form elements.

Comment: eykanal: It applies for all forms inside a draggable object. Therefore I thought there won't be any source code needed.

Comment: Tentonaxe: I thought so, but the handler is the IMG element. So I think the DIV shouldn't be affected by this anymore. Maybe it shouldn't and it is…

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had this same issue. I got the sortable code from the jquery-ui website, and it had the following line of jquery code:

```
$( "#sortable" ).disableSelection();
```

once I commented this out, I was able to edit my forms again. It may work for you. I'm sure this will cause me other headaches (

Answer (score 1):

The solution to this is to just bind a click handler to the form elements after the sortable call and then within the event handler set the focus to 'this', e.g.:

```
jQuery('.sortable-list input[type=text]').click(function(){ jQuery(this).focus(); });
```

Answer (score 0):

I've made a workaround. Because I'm using ajax to load and send the form, I simply don't run the code to make things sortable when the form (with all els to be sortable) is loaded, then when it is sent I make it sortable again. Not solution, but made the job for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
//For disable
$("input, select, textarea").bind('mousedown.ui-disableSelection selectstart.ui-disableSelection', function(e){
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
});
```